# Get all span inside div

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I am accessing the https://footystats.org/ page because I need to get some information from it.
The HTML code is similar as below

```
<span class="timezone-convert-match-regular">07:00pm</span>
<span class="timezone-convert-match-regular">08:00pm</span>
</div>
 <div class="league-data"> Nigeria A
<span class="timezone-convert-match-regular">07:15pm</span>
<span class="timezone-convert-match-regular">08:30pm</span>
</div>
```

I need to show as below

```
Internacional Friendless 07:00pm
Internacional Friendless 08:00pm
Nigeria A 07:15pm
Nigeria A 08:30pm
```

my code python

````
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
for liga, hour in zip( soup.select('div.league-data'), soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'timezone-convert-match-regular'}) ):
    print(liga.text.strip(),hour.text.strip())```
````

Comment: The url you provided does not seem to contain the html you posted here. That makes your question incomplete and your problem not reproducible. My suggestion is to refine your question, either with the url or the actual html. ;)

Comment: @sentence The code is simplified ... do you have any idea how to get all elements inside an element without duplicating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''
 <div class="league-data"> Internacional Friendless
 <span class="timezone-convert-match-regular">07:00pm</span>
<span class="timezone-convert-match-regular">08:00pm</span>
</div>
 <div class="league-data"> Nigeria A
<span class="timezone-convert-match-regular">07:15pm</span>
<span class="timezone-convert-match-regular">08:30pm</span>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

l = [(div.contents[0].strip(), span.text.strip())
    for div in soup.select('div.league-data')
    for span in div.select('span')]

for match, hour in l:
    print(match, hour)
```

Prints:

```
Internacional Friendless 07:00pm
Internacional Friendless 08:00pm
Nigeria A 07:15pm
Nigeria A 08:30pm
```